# php mysql retrive the uploaded photo from the database

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, select

I am trying to display as a result for the search of user list with the identical result retrieved from the database so but the system display the path and not the image itself. 
Can anyone help me?

Until now I started with the query of the search by name:

search.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['login'] != 'true'){
        header("location:index.php");
    }


   $login = ($_SESSION['login']);
   $userid = ($_SESSION['user_id']);
   $login_user = ($_SESSION['username']);
   $fname = ($_SESSION['first_name']);
   $lname = ($_SESSION['last_name']);
   $sessionaddres =($_SESSION['address']);


require_once('for members/scripts/connect.php'); 

// function for selecting names
function nameQuery(){

  $nameData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user") or die("could select database");

  while($record = mysql_fetch_array($nameData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $record['user_name'] .  '">' . $record['user_name'] . '</option>';

  }

}



// function for select by specialization

function specializationQuery(){

$specData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM specialization");

  while($recordJob = mysql_fetch_array($specData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] .  '">' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{


    $Sgov = $_POST['governorate'];
    @$Sdist = $_POST['district'];
    @$Svillage = $_POST['village'];


    // query  search by name
    if(isset($_POST['name']))
    {
        $Sname =$_POST['name'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name, profile_pic FROM user WHERE user_name ='$Sname'")or die(mysql_error());

    if($sql)
    {
     while($getrow = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
     {
        $firstname = $getrow['first_name'];
        $lastname = $getrow['last_name'];
        $profilepic = $getrow['profile_pic'];

        if($profilepic == "") 
         {
             $profile_pic = "images/default_img.jpg";
         }
         else
         {
             $profile_pic = "userdata/profile_pics/".$profilepic;
         }



         echo "<ul>
          <li>
           ".$firstname. " ".$lastname ."
          </li>
          <li>
           <img style='width:80px' src='".$profile_pic . "'>
          </li>
         </ul>";
     }
   }
   else
   {
       echo "their was no result!!!!";
   }
  }
}

// search by specialization

if(isset($_POST['specialization']))
{
    $Sspec = $_POST['specialization'];
    $sql = mysql_query("first_name, last_name, profile_pic FROM user WHERE specialization = '$Sspec'")or die(mysql_error());
    if($sql)
    {
     while($getrow = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
     {
        $firstname = $getrow['first_name'];
        $lastname = $getrow['last_name'];
        $profilepic = $getrow['profile_pic'];

        if($profilepic == "") 
         {
             $profile_pic = "images/default_img.jpg";
         }
         else
         {
             $profile_pic = "userdata/profile_pics/".$profilepic;
         }



         echo "<ul>
          <li>
           ".$firstname. " ".$lastname ."
          </li>
          <li>
           <img style='width:80px' src='".$profile_pic . "'>
          </li>
         </ul>";
     }
   }
   else
   {
       echo "their was no result!!!!";
   }

}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>search page</title>
<link href="style/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
                $("select#district").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#village").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#governorate").change(function(){
                $("select#district").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#district").html("<option>wait...</option>");
                var id = $("select#governorate option:selected").attr('value');
                $.post("select_district.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                    $("select#district").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("select#district").html(data);
                });
            });
            $("select#district").change(function(){ 
            id = $(this).val(); 
            $("select#village").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#village").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            $.post("select_village.php", {id:id}, function(data){


            $("select#village").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#village").html(data);
         });
        });
            $("form#registerform").submit(function(){
                var cat = $("select#governorate option:selected").attr('value');
                var type = $("select#district option:selected").attr('value');
                var village = $("select#village option:selected").attr('value');

            });
    });


</script>
</head>


<body>
<div class="container">
<!--<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>-->
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

  <!-- <?php require_once('leftsideBar2.php'); ?>-->


   <div id="search-title">Search section</div>
    <div id="search-form">
    <?php include "select.class.php"; ?>
        <form action="search.php" method="post">

         Search By Name:<br />
         <select name="name" >
            <?php nameQuery(); ?>
             <option id="0">-- select By UserName --</option>
             </select>
           <br/><br/>
           Search By Governorate:<br />

        <select id="governorate" name = 'governorate'>
                <?php echo $opt->ShowGovernorate(); ?>
                </select>
           <br /><br/>
           Search by District:<br />

      <select id="district" name="district">
                    <option value="0">choose...</option>
                </select>

           <br /><br/>
           Search by Cities:<br />
           <select id="village" name="village">
                    <option value="0">choose...</option>
                </select>
           <br /><br/>
           Search By Specialization:<br />
           <select name="specialization">
             <option id="0" disabled="disabled">-- select Job --</option>

          <?php specializationQuery(); ?>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"  />
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
<?php require_once('footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to place the image path inside an `<img>` tag

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you pick PDO [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   echo "<ul>
          <li>
           ".$firstname. " ".$lastname ."
          </li>
          <li>
           <img src='".$profile_pic . "'>
          </li>
         </ul>";
```

Comment: ok tank you  zavg if i need to resize the picture how to do that  where to put the width =="";

Comment: @user2322046 `<img style="width:100px" src'`

Comment: i will edit my question i added new code  now i get a new error  the system display all users and a user  is displayed twice  my question how to separate  the selection  of the name from the selection of the specialization ???

Answer (score 1):

change this `'.$profile_pic'`  to image tag and put your path in `src` tag

```
<img src=\"$profile_pic\" />
```